# Get a collection of N documents cost with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Get 5 documents from `users/` or from `users/friends/Mike/sister/Jessica/rabbit...` is the same amount of reads on the DB?
I mean, since I need to access to more locations will this increment the amount of reads or it depends only from how many documents I get from the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are charged only for documents that are returned to the client as a result of  query, not for all the documents in the collection.  If you want to limit your costs, you should also place a [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) on the number of documents that the query can receive.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't depend from the path but only from the number of items returned...Ok and I can set a limit with "limit" ok perfect thank you.